# Getting a page token from an app token in Facebook is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to use a Facebook app token instead of a user token to get a page token. But I can only get a page token with user token and not with app token.

Here's what I'm doing. First I get the app token in that way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[app id omitted]&client_secret=[secret omitted]a&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Then I try to get a page token with the app token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page id omitted]?fields=access_token&access_token=[app token omitted]
```

But this is the response:

```
 {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
       "type": "OAuthException",
       "code": 100,
       "fbtrace_id": "[trace id omitted]"
   }
}
```

All the permissions in my app have standard access and I'm the admin of the page. Do I also need advanced permissions?

I tried to inspect my app token with the tool provided here:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/
```

But strangely I don't see any permissions in the output. These are all the info I get after inspection of the token:

```
App ID  [id of the app omitted] : DemoApp
Type    App
```

I wonder if getting a page token from an app token is an allowed operation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

You **can not** get a page token using an app token.

There is no connection between the page and your app - so how would the API determine, whether you are supposed to have access to that particular page to begin with?

Users can be admins/moderators on pages - and therefor *their* tokens can be used to get a page token, because the fact that they are an admin of the page, is what proves access should be granted.

Comment: Doesn't the fact a user is both admin of the page and one of the admin roles in the app proves access should be granted?

Comment: I could, if Facebook had decided to implement it that way, but they didn't. That kind of special scenario is not the norm - for the majority of apps (probably), the people developing the app, and the people who will eventually use it, aren't the same.

Comment: I see. I was hoping I could use an app token as I wanted to avoid any kind of manual process, as I wanted to use this in a back-end. However, it looks like the only way I can get the page token is going through a short lived user token and long lived user token, which imply the use of the Javascript SDK that has a dialog box for login. Is there any way to avoid that UI to get user tokens?

Comment: No, normal user tokens can not be created without user interaction. There are System Users though, their tokens do not expire - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users But that is in the realm of the Business Management API, so if your app is not a "business" app, I don't know if you can use those.